# XSLT: y/n on new field if price difference > 1

Tags: xslt

I am creating a new productfeed and need the following field: `<diff>`.

if difference between price and old_price is more than 1: y (from Yes) in field: `<diff>`

if difference between price and old_price is 1 or less than 1: n (from No) in field: `<diff>`

File: Data.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
 <product id="0001">
  <price>120.00</price>
  <old_price>125.00</old_price>
 </product>
 <product id="0002">
  <price>5.00</price>
  <old_price>5.50</old_price>
 </product>  
</products>
```

Wished output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<products>
 <product id="0001">
  <diff>y</diff>
 </product>
 <product id="0002">
  <diff>n</diff>
 </product>  
</products>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested that but it should be like that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
       <products>
       <xsl:for-each select="//product">
           <diff>
           <xsl:choose>
             <xsl:when test="price - old_price &gt; 1">
              y
             </xsl:when>
             <xsl:otherwise>
              n
             </xsl:otherwise>
           </xsl:choose>
         </diff>
         <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
       </xsl:for-each>
       </products>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Will test and put update

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="price[translate(. - ../old_price, '-', '') > 1]">
    <diff>y</diff>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="price">
    <diff>n</diff>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="old_price" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, this produces:

```
<products>
  <product id="0001">
    <diff>y</diff>
  </product>
  <product id="0002">
    <diff>n</diff>
  </product>
</products>
```